# How to guarantee that a cubic interpolation is monotonic?

Tags: interpolation, mathematical-optimization, cubic

In general: Given an arbitrary set of data that is itself monotonic, how should I calculate an additional n points to force a non-monotonic cubic interpolation (which I have to use, no other choice) to be monotonic?

Specifically for me: I have a project that needs to calculate the relationship between two servos.  Because of the machine design, the servos should never back up.  I wish I could post an image, but I just signed up and don't have the reputation yet.  A representative set of points is as follows:

0: [0, 0] (straight line to 1)

1: [37.5, 45] (cubic curve to 2)

2: [?, ?] (cubic curve to 3)

3: [180, 60] (cubic curve to 4)

4: [?, ?] (cubic curve to 5)

5: [322.5, 75] (straight line to 6)

6: [360, 120] (N/A)

The behavior that I want is characterized by points 0, 1, 3, 5, and 6.  Point 0 is fixed; the rest are calculated at runtime and are guaranteed to increase monotonically.  The entire plot is guaranteed to be symmetric around point 3.  Points 2 and 4 need to be added so that the third-party linear/cubic interpolator that I have to use produces a monotonic curve that is as smooth as possible.  (minimal 2nd derivative)

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of time, I derived a solution myself:

1. Translate the plot to be symmetric about the origin.  (point 3 becomes [0, 0])
2. Find the parabolic segment (constant acceleration) that takes the slope at point 1 to flat at [x, 0].
3. If x has the same sign as point 1, then point 2 = [x, 0], point 4 = [-x, 0], and the segment in between should be linear.
4. If x has the opposite sign or is zero, then the default interpolation is already monotonic.  No additional points required.
5. Once the parabolic segments are determined, in either case, add one more point to each side to convert them to cubic segments.  (constant accel to ramp accel)